# Universal Links - disable top right link

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

I currently complement my web application by using URL Schemes to launch my native application.  Starting with iOS 9 my users now get challenged with a popup that says "Open in *app name*".  I have figured how to eliminate this by using Universal Links using a different domain then the app I'm launching from but have encountered an issue.

Key points

- App is distributed outside of the app store as an Enterprise Distribution.  So if I understand correctly smart app banners do not apply.
- In case my app is not installed, my universal link web location hosts a page on how to install it.
- If a user launches the app but does not have it installed they properly get my install page
- Once in the app if the user presses the domain link at the top right they will not be able to launch the app again

The problem Im encountering is that if a user ever presses on the link/bread crumb at top right the app will not launch anymore.  It will always direct the user to the install page.  I know if I pull down on this page there is an open button that will take me to the app, or if I long press on my link I can also have it launch my app.  However, I will not be able to get my users to understand this.

Is there a way to turn off the link on the top right?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to that?